# View Garbage collectioned variables

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I want to know what all variables are garbage collected in my program and the order of garbage collection. Is there a simple way to do that:

```
class GarbageUtility {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int a =10;
        int b = a;
        int c = a + b;
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

Comment: What technical problem are you trying to solve that you think having this information would help address?

Comment: "I want to know what all variables are garbage collected" <-- by definition you can't: if you have a reference to a variable, it cannot be garbage collected...

Comment: The simplest way would be putting a weak refernce for each of your objects in a list. Then you revisit your list, and you know that the references whose object is `null` has been collected.

Comment: just kidding, of course.

Comment: You don't have any explicit objects in you example, so you know that not objects are created, so none to be collection.  In reality it is likely that Integer.toString() is called, creating an object.

Comment: @SJuan76 - You might be kidding, but that (or something equally intrusive / inefficient / horrible) is probably the best available solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to know what all variables are garbage collected in my program and the order of garbage collection. Is there a simple way to do that:

1. No there isn't<sup>1</sup>.
2. Variables are not garbage collected<sup>2</sup>.  Objects are garbage collected ... or at least, they *may* be garbage collected.
3. Most of the variables in you program have type `int` and `int` is not an object / reference type.  They won't even be affected by the garbage collector.
4. Your program won't even compile ...

---

Footnotes:

1. There are a couple of ways that you can use to infer that an object is *being* garbage collected:

   - If you declare a `finalize()` method, that will be called when the GC detects that the object has no strong, soft or weak references to is ... and garbage collection is imminent.  You can get a similar effect with `Reference` objects and their associated queues.  Note however that this may also *change* the lifetime of the respective objects ... causing them to live longer than they otherwise might.
   - You *might* be able to detect that an object is dues to be garbage collected via the external debugger or profiler agents.  (I'm not sure about this.  I actually think that unreachable objects are invisible to the agents.)
2. Actually, it is a little more complicated than that.

   Variables don't have an independent lifetime.  They are always part of "something else" ... and the "something else" can be garbage collected ... in some cases:

   We can divide variables into 3 kinds:

   - Stack variables (that is method parameters and locals) are not stored in space that is managed by the GC.  Any object whose reference is in a (live) stack variable won't be garbage collected.
   - Instance variables (instance fields declared by a class) are part of the respective object.  When the object is garbage collected, the variables "go away".
   - Static variables (static fields declared by a class) normally stay around for the lifetime of the application.  However, there are circumstances where a class may be garbage collected, and if that happens its static variables go away at the same time.

---

Note that `GarbageCollectionNotificationInfo` tells you that the GC has collected a certain heap, and gives some basic statistics such as how long the GC took and what space was available in the heap before and after.

I don't see how that helps you tell whether specific objects have been garbage collected and when it happened.

Answer (score 4):

you may have a look at `com.sun.management.GarbageCollectionNotificationInfo`, see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/management/extension/com/sun/management/GarbageCollectionNotificationInfo.html

also, this post presents a way to make a gc detector for hashmaps, http://java.dzone.com/articles/letting-garbage-collector-do-c

Comment: Thanks, GarbageCollectionNotificationInfo is what I was looking for.

Comment: How? I don't think it gives you what you're looking for.